# Overwrite HTTP method with JAX-RS

Tags: java, http, rest, jax-rs, http-method

Today's browsers (or HTML < 5) only support HTTP GET and POST, but to communicate RESTful one need PUT and DELETE too. If the workaround should not be to use Ajax, something like a hidden form field is required to overwrite the actual HTTP method.

Rails uses the following trick:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
```

Is there a possibility to do something similar with JAX-RS?

Answer (score 2):

Not strictly a JAX-RS solution but spring 3.0 comes with a [`HiddenHttpMethodFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) that implements exactly the trick that rails does, defaults to the same `_method` parameter.

Note that you don't need to be using all of spring to use this filter, you can just configure it in your `web.xml` and ignore the rest of spring.

Answer (score 1):

Jersey also has something similar, filtering a header field though. Documentation can be found [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/PostReplaceFilter.html)

Answer (score 0):

To quote Roy Fielding:

> In any case, there are **plenty of
>   RESTful services that do nothing but
>   GET and POST**. The key is how those
>   methods are used, not what methods are
>   used. To give a specific example, what
>   makes a wiki more or less RESTful is
>   almost always determined by how it
>   (ab)uses GET and sessions -- whether
>   it uses PUT or POST for editing pages
>   is sugar topping in comparison.

Emphasis is mine, taken from this post
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/10746