# JAX-RS with Jersey: Passing form parameters to PUT method for updating a Resource

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have to update a Person record having firstName and lastName. User should be able to change it from html form and on submit it should be updated.

Here is my code.

```
    @PUT
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public Response updatingResource(@FormParam("firstName") String firstName, @FormParam("lastName ") String lastName , @PathParam("userId") String userId){
        System.out.println(firstName);
        System.out.println(lastName);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

the SOP statements prints null. I have been using Mozilla Firefox's Poster plugin to send PUT request.

I also tried by annotating it with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` but still it is printing null for each values.

How to write and call PUT method that receives these three values. I stumble around lot and found people were asking to use JSON or XML. How can I consume JSON? I would be very greatfull if someone help me to write REST method to update a resource

---

If I send PUT request using Firefox's [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) and Google's [rest-client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) I am able to get the form parameters. Both this tool has something like body section where I placed `firstName=Amit&lastName=Patel`. Also I added header `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.I think Firefox's [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) is buggy. Can anyone suggest me is there any other way I should validate the code or I can trust on first two REST clients?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to annotating your method with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)`, you must send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`as a content-type. Did you do it?

Edited: You can use FormParams only with POST:

> SRV.4.1.1 When Parameters Are Available The following are the
>   conditions that must be met before post form data will be populated to
>   the parameter set:
>
> 1. The request is an HTTP or HTTPS request.
> 2. The HTTP method is POST.
> 3. The content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
> 4. The servlet has made an initial call of any of the getParameter family of methods on the request object. If the conditions are not met
>      and the post form data is not included in the parameter set, the post
>      data must still be available to the servlet via the request object’s
>      input stream. If the conditions are met, post form data will no longer
>      be available for reading directly from the request object’s input
>      stream.

Comment: Yes, I am specifying content type as {application/x-www-form-urlencoded} while sending request

Comment: Oh, didn't pay attention that you use PUT: you must use POST with form parameters.

Comment: If you want to change the resource you should use PUT. POST method is used when you want to create resource. Here I want to change Person details so used PUT. Should I use POST instead?

Comment: Yes, I know, but form parameters will work only with POST. See the edited answer.

Comment: You may also get nulls If you set the "id" tag instead of the "name" tag in your html form field definitions.

So <input type="text" id="username" /> will return null
but <input type="text" name="username" /> will return the proper result.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use an approach as indicated in [Overwrite HTTP method with JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832901/overwrite-http-method-with-jax-rs/5963142#5963142) :

You basically would add a hidden parameter / HTTP header and then POST the form. In your servlet, you prepend a Filter that checks for a certain header / hidden form element and changes the POST into  PUT request. This is forwarded to your ressource and consumed correctly when annotated with PUT.

Comment: With this approach I am able to land POST request with header "X-HTTP-Method-Override" set to PUT but still form parameters are null.

Comment: Hm, hard to tell, after hooking the Filter in your servlet, it should have changed the request as needed. Any errors you get?

Comment: Please check my answer below. I think I was using buggy tool to send REST PUT request

Comment: With the above mentioned method, you should be able to POST (which all browsers can do) and either add the header so that the Jersey filter kicks in or add a hidden form parameter (in case of the Spring filter mentioned in the post). So the request will just be transformed internally - after reaching the server - to the required PUT request.

Answer (score 1):

it is not true that PUT does not accept FormParameters. I use @FormParam with PUT successfully. Maybe it's the @PathParam. I have not tried that.

There seems to be no need for special annotations either. Here is a working class in my application:

```
package ch.sertal.vision.server.services.objectstore;

import ch.sertal.vision.dao.FormDao;
import ch.sertal.vision.dao.PrepopContentDao;
import ch.sertal.vision.model.Form;
import ch.sertal.vision.model.PrepopContent;
import ch.sertal.vision.model.User;
import ch.sertal.vision.model.exceptions.NotLoggedinException;
import ch.sertal.vision.server.services.AbstractSertalService;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Path( "jsonrest/prepop" )
public class PrepopContentStore extends AbstractSertalService {

   @GET
   @Path( "list" )
   @Produces( "application/json" )
   public Response getPrepopEntries( @QueryParam( "formId" ) Long formId ) {
      User user;
      try {
         user = getUser();
      } catch ( NotLoggedinException e ) {
         return Response.status( Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED ).build();
      }

      PrepopContentDao prepopContentDao = new PrepopContentDao( db );
      List<PrepopContent> contentList = prepopContentDao.list( user, formId );

      JSONArray jsPrepops = new JSONArray();
      for ( PrepopContent content : contentList ) {
         jsPrepops.add( prepopContentDao.getJsContent( content, user ) );
      }

      return Response.ok( jsPrepops.toJSONString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE ).build();
   }

   @PUT
   @Produces( "application/json" )
   public Response newPrepopContent( @FormParam( "formId" ) Long formId ) {
      User user;
      try {
         user = getUser();
      } catch ( NotLoggedinException e ) {
         return Response.status( Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED ).build();
      }

      Form form = (new FormDao( db)).get( formId );

      PrepopContent content = new PrepopContent( form, "" );
      content.setTenant( user.getMainTenant() );
      PrepopContentDao prepopContentDao = new PrepopContentDao( db );
      content = prepopContentDao.save( content );

      return Response.ok( prepopContentDao.getJsContent( content, user ).toJSONString(),
                  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE ).build();
   }

}
```

It is called from jQuery like so:

```
    $.ajax( {
       url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/services/jsonrest/prepop",
       type:"PUT",
       async:true,
       data: [{name: "formId", value: that.formId}],
       success:function ( prepopContent ) {
          listContainer.append( "<div>" + template( prepopContent ) + "</div>" );
       }
    } );
```

the ${pageContext.request.contextPath} is from JSP