# Form data to rest PUT method in java

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey

I am beginner for Java and REST API. I have a problem passing form data from HTML to rest `PUT` method. When I google about this, most solutions available are for `POST` method, that recommended to use `FormParam`. In my case, it shows below error:

> The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

Even I use `PathParam`, same error is returned:

> The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

And some solution for Spring Boot. But I did not use that.

**PUT method:**

```
@PUT
@Path("/update")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String updCard(@PathParam("cardNo") String cardNo,  
        @PathParam("reportId") int reportId
        ) throws SQLException { 

    Card c = new Card(cardNo, reportId); 

    System.out.println(cardNo + reportId);
    
    return "";
}
```

**Form:**

```
 <form method="PUT" action="rest/card/update">
  <label for = "cardNo">Card No: </label> <input type="text" name = "cardNo" id = "cardNo"><br/>
  <label for = "reportId">Report Id:</label> <input type="text" name = "reportId" id = "reportId"> <br/>
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
```

So, how do I get the form data in `PUT` method in Jersey?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAX-RS with Jersey: Passing form parameters to PUT method for updating a Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964122/jax-rs-with-jersey-passing-form-parameters-to-put-method-for-updating-a-resourc)

Comment: @AndreiKovrov, let me try. Thanks..

Comment: @AndreiKovrov.. I already saw that.. There also mentioned `FormParm` is only used for `POST`.. and also I tried second answer too, no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by many in [Using PUT method in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8054165/2587435), PUT is not currently supported by the HTML standard. What most frameworks will do is offer a workaround. Jersey has such a workaround with its [HttpMethodOverrideFilter](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/HttpMethodOverrideFilter.java). What you must do is use a POST method and add a `_method=put` query parameter and the filter will switch the POST to a PUT.

You first need to register the filter. If you are using a ResourceConfig just do

```java
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        ...
        register(HttpMethodOverrideFilter.class);
    }
}
```

If you are using a web.xml, then do

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.HttpMethodOverrideFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Then in your HTML, you will just add the `_method=put` query param to the URL. Below is an example I used to test

```html
<form method="post" action="/api/form?_method=put">
    <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        Age:
        <input type="number" name="age"/>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And in your resource method you will use `@PUT` and `@FormParam`s for the paramters

```java
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response form(@FormParam("name") String name,
                     @FormParam("age") String age,
                     @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

    URI redirectUri = UriBuilder
            .fromUri(getBaseUriWithoutApiRoot(uriInfo))
            .path("redirect.html")
            .queryParam("name", name)
            .queryParam("age", age)
            .build();
    return Response.temporaryRedirect(redirectUri).build();
}

private static URI getBaseUriWithoutApiRoot(UriInfo uriInfo) {
    String baseUri = uriInfo.getBaseUri().toASCIIString();
    baseUri = baseUri.endsWith("/")
            ? baseUri.substring(0, baseUri.length() - 1)
            : baseUri;
    return URI.create(baseUri.substring(0, baseUri.lastIndexOf("/")));
}
```

It should work from what I tested

Comment: Thanks Paul, my senior also said that, HTML not support `PUT` method.. so task completed using `GET` method.